# Question about using Replace All where x gets replaced with x-h

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm having a little trouble with replace all.  I'm illustrating horizontal and vertical shifting of basic graphs.  The vertical shifting work fine, but the horizontal shifting does not work and has something to do with my lack of understanding on how replace all works.  Any ideas?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[(f /. x -> (x - h)) + k, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> Text[(f /. x -> (x - h)) + k, {7, 9}], 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10], Range[-10, 10]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]], {{f, x^2, "base function:"}, {x^2, 
   Cos[x] -> "cos(x)"}}, {{k, 0, "k"}, -10, 10, 1}, {{h, 0, "h"}, -10,
   10, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by wrapping the plotting function inside an [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[(f /. x -> (x - h)) + k]
  , {x, -10, 10}
  , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
  , Epilog -> Text[(f /. x -> (x - h)) + k, {7, 9}]
  , GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10], Range[-10, 10]}
  , GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]
  ]
 , {{f, x^2, "base function:"}, {x^2, Cos[x] -> "cos(x)"}}
 , {{k, 0, "k"}, -10, 10, 1}
 , {{h, 0, "h"}, -10, 10, 1}
 ]
```

This seems to be related to the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute of `Plot`, which can cause some counter-intuitive evaluations. The `Evaluate` trick is pretty useful when plotting commands fail to recognize some aspect of the plotting function. For example, the naive attempt

```
Plot[
 Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}]
 , {x, 0, 1}
]
```

will produce a bunch of blue lines - `Plot` will fail to realize that it's been fed six different lines to plot, and that it needs to render them in different colours, unless it's given an explicit `List` header. Wrapping the `Table` inside an `Evaluate` will then produce the desired behaviour.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}]]
 , {x, 0, 1}
]
```

It seems your code falls prey to something similar, since the `ReplaceAll` works fine if you change the `Plot` to a dummy `nonPlottingPlot`, but the details are not that clear to me.

---

Alternatively, switching to pure functions for `f` (rather than expressions) will also fix it:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  f[x - h] + k
  , {x, -10, 10}
  , PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
  , Epilog -> Text[f[x - h] + k, {7, 9}]
  , GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10], Range[-10, 10]}
  , GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]
  ]
 , {{f, #^2 &, "base function:"},
      {#^2 & -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)", Cos -> "cos(x)"}}
 , {{k, 0, "k"}, -10, 10, 1}
 , {{h, 0, "h"}, -10, 10, 1}
]
```